# Link to a facebook user's profile

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, profile

I want to know if it is possible to have a link in my website that goes directly to Facebook user's profile site, with the user logged in, but without the need of the user to log in in Facebook every time the click the link in my website.

Comment: Ok am I understanding you correctly, are you wanting a user to be able to login to facebook and go to their profile page by clicking a link on your website and not having to type in their information?

Answer (score 2):

You can link them to http://facebook.com/me

If they are logged into Facebook, that link will drop them into their profile/timeline page. If not, they will be prompted to login.